# MySql, SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySql 5.7, and I'm getting an error in this query:

```
  SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS sales,
    SUM(amount) AS total,
    created 
  FROM
    `payments` 
  WHERE status =1
  GROUP BY MONTH(created);
```

if I change `GROUP BY MONTH(created)`
with:

```
GROUP BY created
```

then the error is gone. I dont have access to my.ini, to make changes to sql_mode.

Comment: This seems rather self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you group month-wise, you shold output the months also

```
  SELECT COUNT(id) AS sales,
         SUM(amount) AS total,
         MONTH(created)
  FROM payments 
  WHERE status = 1
  GROUP BY MONTH(created)
```

Otherwise MySQL has to pick a `created` value from the group. But you should define what to display.

Another possibility instead of outputting `MONTH(created)` would be a aggreagtion of the date like `min(created)` which would output the earliest date of each month.

Comment: @uergen d, I have tried exactly that, but still getting the same error

Comment: I doubt that. Is that the exact query?

Comment: @uergen d, Sorry my bad. I had both columns "MONTH(created)" and "created". It works perfect now. Thank you.